# Send int array via backgroundworker ReportProgress in c++

Tags: c++, backgroundworker

I'm trying to send an int array from by backgroundworker thread to my main thread by using ReportProgress() method.

Now if I tried to send an integer or a string, it worked ok. but If I try to use an int array it does not seem to work.

How do I solve this problem?

```
private: System::Void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(System::Object^  sender, System::ComponentModel::DoWorkEventArgs^  e) {
    //...do work..
    int foo[5] = { 16, 2, 77, 40, 12071 };
    backgroundWorker1->ReportProgress(99, foo);
}
```

Comment: What does not not seem to work? Do you do some type of data synchronization (mutex, atomic...)?

Comment: I get Error 9 error C2664: 'void System::ComponentModel::BackgroundWorker::ReportProgress(int,System::Object ^)' : cannot convert argument 2 from 'int *' to 'System::Object ^'

Comment: Its not a valid C++ code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> cannot convert argument 2 from 'int *' to 'System::Object ^

C++/CLI allows you to use unmanaged types, like `int foo[5]`.  But they are not convertible to System::Object, the argument type of ReportProgress().  You must use a managed array here.  Fix:

```
 array<int>^ foo = gcnew array<int> { 16, 2, 77, 40, 12071 };
 backgroundWorker1->ReportProgress(99, foo);
```

Your ProgressChanged event handler then needs to cast the Object back to the array:

```
 array<int>^ foo = safe_cast<array<int>^>(e->UserState);
```

---

Noteworthy perhaps is that your original int foo[5] is in fact convertible to IntPtr with a cast which then can be boxed in Object.  But in the specific case of ReportProgress() that will turn out **very** poorly, the variable is long gone by the time that the ProgressChanged event will start running.  ReportProgress doesn't wait for the event handler to complete, under the hood it uses Control::BeginInvoke() instead of Invoke().  Using a managed array that's stored on the heap ensures that this can't go wrong and the array stays valid.  The garbage collector then ensures that the array is released when it is no longer used.

Comment: I'm using it to send a stream of integers sent from an external device to my main thread where it gets written to a file. Do you know of any other way I could do this if ReportProgress is not ok?

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be that the foo parameter you are passing into the ReportProgress function is an integer pointer. It would be helpful if you post the ReportProgress function.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka89zff4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1
I think it should get Object parameter as an overload, but I don't know how to do that with my int array

Comment: you could try using std::array<int, 5> foo = { 16, 2, 77, 40, 12071 }; and passing foo in. int* might not be a System::Object, but std::array should be. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb983093.aspx